# node.js - catch error thrown in a mongoose callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, error-handling, mongoose

In my controller, I have an end point function that calls another function, expecting to get a result or catch errors from the called function.

```
exports.createInvites = (req, res) => { 
  // code...

  try {

    generateInvitations(requirements, data => {

      res.status(200).json({data});
    });

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`caught the error: ${err}`);

    return res.status(500).json(err);
  }
}
```

In the called function `generateInvites`, I save generated object to mongodb using mongoose, and throw an error if there is one.

```
function generateInvitations(requirements, cb) {

  const { expirationDate, credits, numOfUse, numOfInvites } = requirements;
  let invitationCodes = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numOfInvites; i++) {

    const code = randomString(CODE_LENGTH);
    invitationCodes.push(code);

    const invitation = new Invitation({
      // code,
      numOfUse,
      expirationDate,
      credits
    });

    invitation.save((err, obj) => {

      if (err) {
        throw err; // it should throw a ValidationError here
      }
    });
  }
  cb(invitationCodes);

}
```

Above code is my attempt to handle errors thrown in `generateInvites`. Of course, I wasnt able to catch any error. What did I do wrong? and what should I do instead ?

Comment: you should look into promises. async error handling is ugly with callbacks. promises make it much more.. civilized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deal with the fact that the callback will fire long before an error would be thrown, as it's in a callback of it's own. I would suggest [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait on all save operations, which return promises.

```
function generateInvitations(requirements) {
  const { expirationDate, credits, numOfUse, numOfInvites } = requirements;
  let promises = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < numOfInvites; i++) {
    const code = randomString(CODE_LENGTH);

    const invitation = new Invitation({
      // code,
      numOfUse,
      expirationDate,
      credits
    });

    promises.push(invitation.save());
  }
  return Promise.all(promises):
}
```

And then:

```
generateInvitations(requirements)
  .then(data => res.status(200).json({data}))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(`caught the error: ${err}`);
    return res.status(500).json(err);
  });
```

Comment: Your code contains one critical bug, `generateInvitations` will be resolved before all save operations are finished, and even an error will be raised it won't be processed. You must use `Promise.all` or `Promise.map` there.

Comment: mongoose functions return promises, so you don't need to create a promise and use `reject, resolve` callbacks. Just return result of save function: `promises.push(invitation.save())`.

Comment: @aw04 Thanks for your help. what if I want to get saved `Invitation` instance in `generateInvitations`?

Comment: You could do invitation.save().then(data => ...) the same way you did on the outside, only in this case data will just be the current one